# Which is the longest book published in Esperanto?

Tags: culture, literature

I stumbled across [this article](http://www.shortlist.com/entertainment/books/the-10-longest-novels-ever-written) and started wondering about Esperanto. Could someone have translated Proust's novel? Would there be a market for it? Anyway, I want to know which book, preferably in a single volume, is the longest. Measure in pages, words, or even characters, whichever makes most sense.
I'm interested in both original and translation works, of course.

In short:
Which is the longest book published in Esperanto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this is best answered by someone who works at an Esperanto library. I am not sure, but I can give you a list of contenders. I don't own these books, so I can only judge by the reported number of pages.

The standard translation of the Bible has a total of 2255 pages, 1760+495, in the Inko edition (which uses the normal format of a paperback book). The book *ADORU: Ekumena Diserva Libro* (2001) has 1492 pages.

The four classic Chinese novels are similar in length, but it looks as though the translation of *Pilgrimo al la Okcidento* holds the record for a translation of one work by one person, with 1976 pages.

### Translations

From Chinese:

- *Ruĝdoma sonĝo* (tr. Xie Yuming, 1997): 1893
- *Ĉe akvorando* (tr. Laŭlum, 2004): 1830
- *Romano pri la Tri Regnoj* (tr. Laŭlum, 2008): 1807
- *Pilgrimo al la Okcidento* (tr. Laŭlum, 2009): 1976

From other languages:

- *La mastro de l' ringoj* (tr. William Auld, 1997): 1158
- *La grafo de Montekristo* (tr. Daniel Moirand, 2010): 1184

### Original novels

Longest novel in Esperanto (by reported number of pages), in succession:

- *Kastelo de Prelongo* (Henri Vallienne, 1907): 515
- *Idoj de Orfeo* (H.J. Bulthuis, 1923): 542
- *La granda kaldrono* (John Islay Francis, 1978): 592
- *Tarokoj kaj epokoj* (Christian Declerck, 2003): 656

There are two other novels with more than 600 pages, *La princo ĉe la hunoj* (Eugène de Zilah, 2011) and *Morto de artisto* (Anna Löwenstein, 2008). I have to point out however that *Kastelo de Prelongo* has 700 pages in the Inko edition, so these lists do not give a reliable ranking order.

For translated non-fiction, there is *La kapitalo, unua volumo* (Wilhelm Luttermann, 2011): 762 pages. For poetry, there is *Testamente: plena originala poemaro* (Edwin De Kock, 2015): 698 pages.